# Check if an option matches all the value in a list

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in MySQL, products and product_options. A product can have more than an option type.

Table product:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Croissant |
| 2 | Croissant Medium |
| 3 | Coffee |

Table product_options:

| id | type | value | productId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | weight | 40 | 1 |
| 2 | weight | 60 | 2 |
| 3 | weight | 6 | 3 |
| 4 | size | small | 3 |

As you can see, all the products have the option type *weight* set, while the option type *size* is set only for the product with id 3.
I'm trying to have a query only, that returns if a product option is set for all the products.

I'm expecting as result a mysqli object with a boolean for each product option type, to flag if the product option type is set for all the products.

In the example case should be:

| optionType | allProductsHaveIt |
| --- | --- |
| weight | true |
| size | false |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT product.id,
       product.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(product_options.type) present_options,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN product_options.type IS NULL
                         THEN options_list.type
                         END ) absent_options
FROM product
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT type
             FROM product_options ) options_list
LEFT JOIN product_options ON product.id = product_options.productId
                         AND options_list.type = product_options.type
GROUP BY product.id, product.name;
```

> What I need, is given the list of options, what option is present in all the products.

```sql
SELECT product_list_per_option.type,
       products_list.products_list IS NOT NULL AllProducesHaveIt
FROM ( SELECT type, GROUP_CONCAT(productId ORDER BY productId) products_list
       FROM product_options
       GROUP BY type ) product_list_per_option
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY id) products_list
            FROM product ) products_list USING (products_list)
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=257439582a57eb8e9d81bbb8de2958aa

Comment: Interesting answer. But I need a result from the option perspective. In your example you list what options are present or absent for a given product. What I need, is given the list of options, what option is present in all the products. So for example in the example case, "weight" is present in all the products, and "size" is not present in all the products

Comment: @poisons Add desired output for shown data into your question text. As MySQL output (formatted table).

Comment: I did at the end of the question

Comment: @poisons Possible solution added.

Comment: It works flawlessy, thanks, you theached me something new.